# How to inset (or fill in) a complicated mesh?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

I have SVG of a tree. I want to make a 3D model of it. Also I want to add a texture on the front face (on the trunk) of this tree, to make it bumpy. But how can I add a 3d texture on it?
I extruded the perimeter, but how to fill in the rest?
[image: svg file]
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Don't miss out on some bonus points from taking the tour: http://blender.stackexchange.com/tour Please ask only one question at a time. When there are multiple questions, it's hard to pick a "best" answer. If you'd like information about texturing, you can post another question. If you don't... that's fine, too. You can edit your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways that you could potentially approach this:

1. Manually select 4 vertices, press `f` to make a face, and repeat until you go crazy.
2. Select all of the vertices and press `f` to make an "n-gon", you'll quickly realize why n-gons are avoided.
3. Another option is the Face Tools built into Blender.

   *From [the Manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html?highlight=beautify):*

   > **Fill**
   >
   > The Fill option will create triangular faces from any group of selected edges or vertices, as long as they form one or more
   >   complete perimeters.
   >
   > Note, unlike creating n-gons, fill supports holes.
   >
   > **Beauty Fill**
   >
   > - Mode: Edit Mode
   > - Menu: Mesh ‣ Faces ‣ Fill/Beautify Fill
   > - Hotkey: Alt-Shift-F
   >
   > Beautify Fill works only on selected existing faces. It [rearranges] selected triangles to obtain more “balanced” ones (i.e.
   >   less long thin triangles).

   Check out the Manual link. It's got even more information.

Answer (score 2):

When you import an SVG file it will become a curve object in blender.
You have the option to make curves filled:

[image]

(to make the example I traced the image on your post, then imported it to blender as svg and joined all of the curves into 1, but you don't need to join all of them)

Answer (score 0):

This definitely looks like the perfect job for a curve object, not a mesh.

If you imported it as an SVG try re-importing it and not converting to a mesh. Blender will then take care of automatically filling the face loops.

You can then convert to mesh afterwards for further processing if needed.

Answer (score -1):

To Fill in the mesh select all the vertices and hit "F" for face. this will fill in your space with an Ngon. When you go to uv unwrap it, select "project from view" so that your bump map will not get stretched. If you need help texturing it there are plenty of resources out there.
It also looks like you have extruded your vertices backward. If you want to fill in the front and back make sure and select the front ones and the back ones separately when you are filling them so that you get a clean structure.

Comment: Bad idea for something this complex. N-Gons are a no-no, but the more complex your model becomes the more you're likely to run into issues.