# Why don´t certain shapes/faces extrude?

Tags: modeling, extrude

[image: shape]

So i am working on a project, where i created a shape based on an image, but when i extrude it certain areas just won´t extrude right. As you see in the screenshot there are no "walls" at some places.
 Why is that? I guess that i used a couple techniques in the process to create vertecies, that apparently don´t work well together.On the other hand i don´t see why this should be a thing. Is there a way to assimilate the condition of the whole mesh so it extrudes normaly?

Comment: Most likely because the base you're extruding was already extruded once and has double vertices (and faces, which is visible if looking at the edge of the base faces, there are dots indicating hidden or zero-area faces).

Comment: Oh, thanks. removing the doubles solved the problem. I thought of having done that before...

Comment: Also this looks like the kind of job a bezier curve object would be most suited for, rather than a mesh. Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53910/how-to-inset-or-fill-in-a-complicated-mesh

Answer (score -1):

Removing doubles may fix it in this case, but similar results may show with wonky normals, generally fixed by Ctrl+n in Edit mode

Comment: I don't think bad normals would ever result in an issue like this. All that would happen is the extruded mesh may have weird normals.