# I need some help making a face on an irregular shape I imported from Autocad please

Tags: bezier-curves, faces

I have an irregular shape with holes in the middle and I am finding it difficult to create faces for quickly, does anyone have any suggestions? [image: screenshot of the irregular shape with holes inside, only vertices and edges]

Comment: Found this [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53910/how-to-inset-or-fill-in-a-complicated-mesh). It seems similar and might have the answer you're looking for.

Comment: That looked like the perfect solution, but alas it still didn't work. In fact nothing changed at all. Thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edges are discontinued, you need to select all and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*, then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> to fill, and <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* to dissolve all the edges that have been created:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately alt f only fills half of the whole thing, I think on simpler shapes this would work perfect.

Comment: Coud you please share your file?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=Wr1ZQ7KP" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/Wr1ZQ7KP/) 

I converted one to a mesh, and left one as curves to see if its easier one way or the other

Comment: Your edges are discontinued, you need to select all and M > Merge by Distance, then Alt F

Comment: Tried that after posting, but still didn't work. Did it work for you? I'm not discarding my own user error at all in all this.

i got it to work nevermind, you're a star

Comment: Yes it works, see my edit, I'm talking about the mesh, not the curves, of course, for the curves you first need to convert to mesh

Comment: At this point though I feel separating the holes and then booling them in would have a better effect, as the back face would be extruded. Anyway, case closed. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: As a way to avoid the lines created from having holes in the mesh

Comment: You can't avoid edges, you can't create a hole in a face without some edges connecting the inner edges to the outer edges, if this is what you're referring to?

Comment: Yes, I have more success solidifying a non hole mesh, then booling in the holes after. But thank you for teaching me this method, it's definitely better.